# Caching downloaded information with vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, vue.js

I have a list of items rendered in a vue component. This items need to load some information from a service. For example the item icon, caption, etc.

Is there any way in vue to download this information only once and be reused next time the same items are shown to the user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you talking about a same SPA session, or cross session in a same browser?

Comment: I think that you should store the information in `local storage` and fetch data from it if has.